# Tracking post parameters

Tags: post, fiddler

I am traversing through pages in a  website that is made in PHP.The pagination is like 1 to 400.If I move from page 1 to Page 2 , how do I track which parameters are passed.I guess it uses post and not get?Can I use fiddler for that?

Comment: Generally you should be able to do so. Can you share the URL?

Comment: http://sppp.rajasthan.gov.in/bidlist.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler can definitely help you with that. All you have to do is just choose the "Raw" tab and you'll find what you're looking for:

[image]